# Es correcto este tipo de igualdad en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Un instructor escribió lo siguiente

```
function esVocal(letra){
  if(letra.length === 1){
    if(
      letra === "a" || 
      "A" || 
      letra === "e" || 
      "E" || 
      letra === "i" || 
      "I" || 
      letra === "o" || 
      "O" || 
      letra === "u" || 
      "U"
    ){
      return "Es vocal";
    } 
  } else {
    return "Dato incorrecto"
  }
}
```

Mi consulta es si decir `letra === "a" || "A"` es correcto, o sea, si está bien lo de poner el operador or. Gracias!

Comment: Y pornque en vez de validad ambos casos no convierte conviertes minúscula y solo evaluas la minúscula??

Comment: Y creo que lo más simplofocado es hacer `if( ["a","e","i","o","u"].includes(letra.toLowerCase())){}`

Comment: @Christian sé que hay muchos métodos para trabajar la letra que llega por parámetro, pero mi duda apunta a saber si lo de `letra === "a" || "A"` es correcto...si esa expresión está bien así

Comment: Es una [igualdad estricta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) y sí es válido, ya que con esto te aseguras que sean iguales tanto en valor como en tipo.

Comment: La sintaxis es correcta pero la lógica nop, si quieres saber si `letra` tiene cualquiera de los 2 valores debes hacer una comparación por cada valor

Comment: @Christian o sea que si seguiría el patrón de como se iba planteado el condicional if se vería algo como `letra === "a" || letra === "A" || letra === "e" || letra === "E" || letra === "i" || letra === "I" || letra === "o" || letra === "O" || letra === "u" || letra === "U"`

Comment: Pues sip. Por eso te daba algunas formas más compactas de hacerlo

Comment: Genial. Gracias @Christian !

Comment: ¡Es horrendo! :(

Answer (score 6):

No, no es correcto. Lo que estarías diciendo con esta expresión:
`letra === "a" || "A"` 
es que si letra es igual a 'a', devuelva true (`true || 'A'`), pero si no, devuelva 'A' (`false || 'A'` evalua a 'A') y ya no evalúa el resto. Despues, como 'A' se evalua como verdadero, sin importar la letra que pongas, tu función va a devolver 'Es vocal'.

Comment: Eso es lo que se conoce como falsy  o truthy?
Perdón por mi ignorancia.

Comment: Si, justamente una cadena de caracteres que no esta vacia es un valor 'truthy'. La comparacion `letra === 'a'` es true o false. En general truthy es un valor que no es necesariamente `true` pero que se evalua como verdadero (numeros diferentes a 0, `[]`, `{}`, cadenas de caracteres que no estan vacias...), y falsey no es necesariamente`false` pero evalua como false ( `''`, 0)

Comment: Excelente. Gracias por la explicación!

Answer (score 4):

No es correcto si se pretende evaluar `letra === "A"`.

En `letra === "a" || "A"` lo que sucede es una [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), simplificando podría ser así:

```
(primera parte) || segunda_parte
```

Siempre se evalúa de izquierda a derecha y cuando existe un OR lógico JavaScript intenta hacer una evaluación *short-circuit*. Que funcionaría asi:

Si `primera parte` es **verdadera** la segunda parte **no se evalúa** en absoluto, sea lo que sea.

Si `primera parte` es **falsa** la segunda parte **se evalúa**. En el ejemplo se evalua `"A"`.

```js
console.log(true || "A");
console.log(false || "A");

console.log(true || alert("nada se va a ejecutar"));


//El AND lógico también tiene una evaluación short circuit

console.log(true && alert("short circuit con AND"));
```

Es decir que esta expresión no sirve para hacer `letra === A`, aunque la primera parte (`letra === "a"`) sea falsa el siguiente paso será evaluar la segunda parte, y la evaluación de `"A"` es `"A"` (ampliación mas adelante).

En el código, además pones algo como:

```
letra === "a" || "A" || una_tercera_parte
```

En ese caso, si `letra === "a"` fuese falso, de manera de que se evalúa `"A"`, existe otra evaluación *short-circuit* conformada por:

```
"A" || una_tercera_parte
```

Y en este caso, la evaluación de `"A"` es `true`, no `"A"` como antes, porque entra en juego el concepto de [coerción](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion). Que es:

> ... la conversión automática o implicita de valores de un tipo de dato
> a otro ...

Sea una evaluación *short-circuit* o no, la primera parte de un OR lógico si o si necesita ser `true` o `false`, es decir necesita ser un booleano para continuar. Y lo que va a pasar es que se intenta transformar el dato en `true` o `false`.

Los strings no vacíos (entre otros), son lo que se denomina [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy), son valores que en la coerción (en la necesidad de cambiarlos) caen en la vereda de los verdaderos. Es decir que si fuera imperioso cambiar el dato a algún booleano, son `true`. Por supuesto también están los [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), son aquellos que si hay que convertir a `true` o `false` se convierten en `false`.

```js
console.log(false || "A" ||  "nunca se va a evaluar"); // --> A es truthy

console.log(false || true  ||  "nunca se va a evaluar");

console.log(false || 0 ||  "se va a evaluar"); // --> 0 es falsy
```

Volviendo al caso de `false || "A"` es necesario notar que no existe una coerción de `"A"`, la expresión `false || false` es `false`, es decir, se va a retornar lo que sea que sea la segunda parte cuando exista algo como `false ||` .

```js
console.log(false || 0); // <-- no hay coercion en 0
```

Volviendo al ejemplo, en esta expresión:

```
      letra === "a" || 
      "A" || 
      letra === "e" || 
      "E" || 
      letra === "i" || 
      "I" || 
      letra === "o" || 
      "O" || 
      letra === "u" || 
      "U"
```

cualquier valor de `letra` distinto de `"a"` va a retornar `"A"` y `a` va retornar `true`, nunca va a evaluar mas que hasta `"A"`, como está dentro de un if, el retorno `"A"` va a ser coercionado a `true`, osea que siempre va a ser `true`.

Comment: Tremenda explicación. Muchísimas gracias!!!